# Why nested structure is needed in singly linked list?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, struct, singly-linked-list

I'm new to data structures and algorithms. Right know I'm learning singly linked lists and I'm confused with a piece of code that creates a linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 36; 
    head->next = NULL;

    printf("%d", head->data);
}
```

My question is why we have to use `struct node *next;` part in order to refer to memory location of next node.
Why can't we instead use `int *next`?

Comment: If you would use `int *next` then your struct would not represent a linked list. It will simply be a struct with an integer and an integer pointer.

Comment: `int *next;` makes the variable `next` point to a single `int` value. How would that single `int` value be able to continue point to further nodes in the list? You need a list of *nodes*, where each node contains the data (the `int` value) and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: And a little nitpicking: `struct node *next;` doesn't really *nest* structures. A nested structure would be one structure object directly inside another structure object. `next` isn't a structure object, it's a *pointer* to a structure object.

Comment: If you believe it can be written with `int*` instead of `struct node *`, why not try to write that code, construct a linked list (for example of the numbers 1 to 10), and see what problems emerge?

Comment: I edited your question a little, keeping (I believe) the core of your question, will buffing readability and clarity of used terms. I hope you perceive it as improvement. Otherwise feel free to undo and in that case please accept my apology.

Answer (score 2):

This definition

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

explains
"This is a node, carrying info on an int and pointing to another node (if not NULL), which in turn might point to yet another node... and so on."
A typical linked list.

This is what I understand your alternative to be:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    int *next;
};
```

And it would explain:
"This is a node, carrying info on an int and pointing to another int (if not NULL)."
But an int cannot provide access to yet another int. So this one can provide access to info on one or two ints.
The idea of a linked list, in contrast, is however that it can (assuming memory) provide access to an indeterminate and quite high number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you may write like

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    int *next;
};
```

To allocate the head node you can write (as you already did)

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

head->data = 36; 
head->next = NULL;
```

If you want to allocate the next node you have to write

```
head->next = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

But to assign values to the newly created node you have to write

```
( ( struct node * )head->next )->data = 37;
( ( struct node * )head->next )->next = NULL;
```

Such a code will only confuse readers of the code.

That is you are allocating memory for an object of the type `struct node` but then you are interpreting the pointer to the allocated memory as having the type `int *` instead of using a pointer of the type `struct node *`.  And then again to assign values tp an object of the type `struct node` you need to cast the pointer of the type `int *` to the type `struct node *`. Such a code is error-prone.